# What nondairy milk does not curdle when heated?

Tags: substitutions, milk

I like to heat my milk for coffee (and use the microwave to do so) but I find with Soya Milk it curdles. Does anyone know of any other non-dairy milk that one can heat in a microwave please?

Comment: Curdles during heating, or curdles when mixed into coffee (which some brands of soymilk have a known tendency to)?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment (taken me a while to figure out and get into the site) yes I think you're right, it curdles when  mixed with the coffee. Must be some kind of chemical reaction presumably as soya milk is absolutely find in tea.

Comment: related https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/94595/why-does-coconut-milk-separate-in-coffee

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the curdling happens when added to the coffee:

Hot soymilk is even more sensitive to curdling from acids than dairy milk. UHT (soymilk, not dairy) varieties are generally considered less prone to that effect, trying these might be worth it.

Oatmilk is often considered the best nondairy alternative for this scenario.

If palatable, this trick could also help:

[Why does salt prevent soy milk from curdling in hot coffee?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/30060/why-does-salt-prevent-soy-milk-from-curdling-in-hot-coffee)

Comment: Very interesting! I'll definitely try the salt test. But equally will try some oat milk - not sure I've even seen it in the supermarket but will go on a hunt. Thanks!